# 14.04 w/ Intel HD 4000 display crashes when changing resolution

Tags: display, resolution, intel-graphics, crash, flicker

So, I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 over spring break because MATE seems to have gotten to a point that it is generally usable with Compiz for me. I did a minimal install, and put MATE on top of that, and everything was working fine. This is on a System76 gazp7, so *only* the Intel HD 4000 Graphics (no dual-graphics setup like the questions I keep finding when I search), native resolution 1920×1080.

I know that at the beginning of this week I was able to connect my television just fine over HDMI, but now when I try to change the resolution (either activating a second display, or even with just the built in display changing resolution) the screen(s) start to flicker and everything becomes unresponsive.

When I kill the display with Ctrl + Alt + Backspace I am able to regain control of everything, but this leaves me with only one display again. I have been trying to dig through everything I installed in the past week to find anything that looks display-related, but I can not find much. I tried getting the xorg-edgers PPA but it not only failed to fix my issue, it also broke window decorations.

When I launch Red Eclipse (game), my screen changes to 1360×768 and back just fine, no flickering or failing to update or losing responsiveness. I am not sure why that works, but since it involves changing the resolution and it works I thought I would add that.

Is anyone aware of what might cause this, or does anyone have ideas on where I can poke to try to get better information about why this is happening?

Comment: to use compiz, open a terminal and type `nohup compiz --replace`

Comment: I already have Compiz working fine, and it was in use when multiple displays worked earlier in the week. Does this command do something that changes how displays are handled?

Comment: this command changes your display manager to compiz (however, it doesn't always stick across boots)

Comment: I think `mate-tweak` already addressed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compiz flickering, install compiz-config-settings-manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings-manager
```

to run:

```
ccsm &
```

Then, click on open-gl and set texture filter to fast and set the same as shown here (lighting off, sync to vblank on, texture compression off, framebuffer, vertex and always use buffer swapping all on.

[image]

Next, click on composite, disable slow animations, enable detect refresh rate, set refresh rate to ac freq, and force independent you can experiment with.

[image]

Now, disable copy to texture and maybe disable all animations unless you actually want any of those.

Finally, with mate, I believe you should have the mate plugin enabled as well.

For window decorations, enable the window decoration plugin.

Comment: That actually fixed it. I suppose I would have to experiment to figure out which part of the configuration did it, but I followed everything except the Gnome part. I almost asked first, but figured I would try changing from MATE Compatibility to Gnome Compatibility last (because there was some strange behavior that switching to MATE Compatibility fixed). Thank you for that. I wonder why that changed mid-week? Well, anyway, this makes homework quite a bit easier having dual monitors back.

Comment: @Spencer cool, i haven't seen the mate plugin. Last I tried compiz in mate I believe it was still using gnome. I'll change that.