# Ubuntu 22.04 logs out when display settings change

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I just came back to Ubuntu after quite some time. After installing 22.04, I'm running into a weird issue that I can't seem to find a resolution for.

Whenever a display setting changes, I get logged out. It happens when I disable or enable a display, and also when I change the primary display. That in itself isn't a big deal since I'm not changing display settings very often. What is really frustrating though is that I also get logged out when the machine is idle and Ubuntu attempts to put the screens to sleep.

I've tried disabling all extensions, but that hasn't helped. I found an [outdated question that suggesting using compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605442/14-04-w-intel-hd-4000-display-crashes-when-changing-resolution), but it looks like compiz is no longer in the repos and I'm hesitant to try such an outdated solution.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a "logout". You seem to be describing *crashes* of the desktop stack.

Comment: @user535733 You're almost certainly right, but from a user perspective all I see is that I've been logged out and I wanted phrase the question in the way that would be helpful to what other users would see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hunting for quite some time, I found [another outdated answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727364/display-manager-crashes-on-dual-monitors-with-gnome-3) that pointed me in the direction of what turned out to be a good solution.

In short, the desktop stack was crashing, forcing a logout. I just needed to switch to the latest NVIDIA drivers.

I followed the instructions in [this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) to do so.

They suggest two alternate ways:

#### GUI

1. Open the Software & Updates application
2. Select the Additional Drivers Tab
3. Choose the highest numbered NVIDIA driver
4. Click "Apply Changes"
5. Reboot

#### Command Line

1. `ubuntu-drivers devices`
2. Look for a line with "recommended" in it like this `driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free recommended`
3. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` OR install the specific driver listed in the previous step like this `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510`
4. `sudo reboot`

I used the GUI method, but I also used the first command in the command line option to verify that the highest numbered one in the GUI was also the recommended driver for my specific device.